# Должен ли я чистить обработчики на UnityEvent'е при уничтожении объекта?

Tags: c#, unity3d

Я знаю, что если объект, владеющий событием, остается существовать, то в коде уничтожаемого объекта нужно отписаться от события, иначе обработчики так и останутся висеть, делая тормоза при его вызове и не давая GC собрать объект.

У меня же объект, владеющий событием (а именно кнопка), уничтожится вместе с объектом, который на нее подписан. Будет ли чистка обработчиков события избыточной в данной ситуации?

Comment: хз как в юнити, но в дотнете, если вы уничтожаете все ссылки на эти два объекта, то они сколько хочешь могут ссылаться друг на друга, это не важно, GC их всё равно переварит

Comment: Бенчмарк в помощь, в юнити есть замечательный [`Profiler.GetMonoUsedSizeLong`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Profiling.Profiler.GetMonoUsedSizeLong.html).

Comment: @RiotBr3aker спасибо, попробую этот способ.